# graph theory homework

Tags: graph-theory

I have some problems with figuring out these questions about simple graphs.
I'm not sure if I'm doing this right.

**1.How many different graphs $G=(V,E)$ exist with $V=\{1,2,...,n\}$.**
There are $\binom{n}{2}$ different edges. So there $2^{\binom n2}$ different subsets of edges.
**2. How many different regular graphs with degree 2 exist and $V=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$**
I think $\binom{5}{2}$ options to not get a cycle and $\binom{5}{2}\cdot3\cdot2$ options to get a cycle of length $6$.
**3. Prove that every graph with $n\geq 2$ vertices, has two vertices with the same degree.**
Assume they are all different. The largest can't have degree $\geq n$. As they are all different they must have degree $0,1,...,n-1$. But then the largest one is connected to all. Contradiction as one vertice must have degree $0$.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. What is a graph with degree 2? 3. Yes.

Comment: @dtldarek I mean that all the vertices have degree 2.

Comment: Those are called 2-regular graphs. I would calculate it by $\frac{1}{2}\binom{6}{3}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{6!}{6}$, but you are right. Check also [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A001205).